# GM: Difference in open a new window direct/on button click

Tags: greasemonkey

First of all, I have no Idea what I'm doing exactly, secondly I hope my english is quite good enough.
My favourite website recently changed its look and feel, therefor I try to reanimate the "old" style via Greasemonkey. So far everything works but I have an issue opening a window for a comment. This comment(field) is now part of the site itself and no loger a free floating window.
What i did is adding this to the script:

```
var newWin = open('','write a comment','height=300,width=600');
newWin.document.write('<html><head><title>Write a comment</title></head></head><body bgcolor="#555555" text="#000000" topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" style="overflow:hidden;"><form id="commentForm" name="photoComment" action="http://[...]/add_photo_comment/38060403" method="post"reloadUrl="[...]/photo-comments/38060403/de/page/1"data-ua-submit="Fotodetailseite;Kommentar verfassen;Foto;38060403"><div class="media-left"><div class="media-body"><div class="form_row"><textarea id="photoComment_comment" name="photoComment[comment]" required="required" rows="5" class="form-control write-comment" placeholder="Anmerkung"></textarea></div><div class="row fcx-space-tiny"><div class="col-lg-12 text-right"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm submit-comment"><i class="icon icon-comment"></i>send</button></div></div></div></html>');
```

Sofar this works for me when inserting the code directly into the script (window opens on entering the site directly)

As far as I wrap it in a function, the new window will be opened but without contetnt:

```
var input=document.createElement("input");
input.type="button";
input.value="Anmerkung";
input.onclick = createComment;
input.setAttribute("style", "font-size:18px;position:absolute;top:80px;left:40px;");
document.body.appendChild(input); 

function createComment()
{
[exactly the same script as above]
};
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for help

Comment: Maybe you can post your error message it will be useful to recognize your question

Comment: Up to now, I don't know how to get error messages. Please support.